# How to change color of QTextEdit widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit

I'm trying to change the color of a QTextEdit to black, regardless if there's text or none, to give it a terminal look. It seems to me that the default white background color of QTextEdit (PyQy4) can't be changed by means that are otherwise working for other Qt widgets. I have tried the following:

```
w.setTextBackgroundColor(QColor(0,0,0))

w.setAutoFillBackground(True)

p = w.palette()
p.setColor(w.backgroundRole(), QColor(0,0,0))
w.setPalette(p)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution is using `qss`:

```
w.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
```

If you want to use `QPalette` you should apply it to the viewport():

```
p = w.viewport().palette()
p.setColor(w.viewport().backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))
wt.viewport().setPalette(p)
```

Comment: Thank you. `viewport()` worked. `setStyleSheet()` didn't tho.

Comment: @DorkOrc It works for me both. Maybe the style you use is blocking that property. :P

Comment: Both options work for me, though with the stylesheet method the scrollbar is also affected (which looked weird for me).